# Symfony и fastcgi_finish_request

Tags: php, service, symfony, события, fastcgi

Развернут адаптер бизнес логики на Symfony 3.1, требуется организовать работу сервисов с fastcgi_finish_request, вопрос - есть ли какой-нибудь Event, который позволяет попасть за пределы вывода, чтобы добавить работу в фоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие [kernel.terminate](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-terminate)